# using pdf library for making pdf viewer in c# , java , python , c/c++ and android

Tags: c#

i want to make simple pdf viewer , I know C# , java , python , c/c++ and android but i prefer C#  , is there any pdf library in dotNetframeWork or free dll . can you guys suggest me pdf library for above language's ? what is the best language for this work ?

Answer (score 0):

use pdflib, which is what i'm using in generating PDF.

for more information, [here](http://pdflib.com/)